# Linear Trend for Stock Price Prediction

Tags: time-series, stationarity, trend

I have a very simple, and probably a stupid question. Though, I would like to ask. Suppose we have $Y_1,...,Y_N$ price observations of a particular stock. I assume that $Y_{N+1}$ can be forecasted using linear trend, so it is needed to estimate parameters of the following equation:
$$Y_t=\alpha+\beta\times t+\epsilon_t.$$
By definition, time series $t$ is non-stationary, then how we can explicitly estimate equation in the above form using OLS?

Comment: The issue isn't $t$, it's $\epsilon_t$. That's what needs to be stationary to use OLS. For a stock price, typically you'll have a unit root and so the above will not hold with stationary $\epsilon_t$.

Comment: If so, then how one can estimate linear trend for stock price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y_t$ contained a linear trend plus a stationary component, you could use OLS to estimate the parameters of the model. The estimator would be hyperconsistent; it would converge to the true value at the rate of $n^{3/2}$ rather than the usual $n^{1/2}$ where $n$ is the sample size. Thus you would only need a relatively small sample to obtain relatively accurate results compared to a model in which the regressor is not trending (though admittedly this is an asymptotic argument). See Hayashi "Econometrics" p. 160-163 for a more detailed treatment.

Since you are modeling a stock price, $\log(Y_t)$ likely is a unit-root process which mean $Y_t$ is something more nasty with possibly an exponential trend. The original model is then not well specified. A cleaner alternative might be to work with $x_t:=\Delta y_t:=\Delta\log(Y_t)$ and model it as $x_t=\gamma+\varepsilon_t$ with both $x_t$ and $\varepsilon_t$ plausibly stationary.

If we leave stock prices alone and focus on a correctly specified model $Y_t=\alpha+\beta t+\varepsilon_t$ with $\varepsilon_t$ being either stationary or a unit-root process, OLS will yield a consistent estimator of $\beta$ because a linear thrend stochastically dominates both a stationary process and a unit-root process (similarly to how a unit-root process dominates a stationary process).

Comment: Thanks for this! I do understand that if $Y$ and $t$ are cointegrated that I can estimate the equation using OLS. But, what if they are not cointegrated? Does not this yield to a spurious regression? Thanks!

Comment: @Duo, $Y$ and $t$ cannot be cointegrated because $t$ is not a unit-root process. What you are alluding to regards stochastic trends and makes sense on its own but does not apply to deterministic time trends as here.

Comment: Chris Haug has a good point which I initially overlooked. I have edited my answer to incorporate it.

Comment: Thanks! If I estimate $x_t=\gamma+\epsilon_t$ model, where $x_t=\Delta log(Y_t)$, then how I convert this to my initial parameter $\beta$ (slope of the line)?

Comment: @Duo, there is no linear slope as such, because the trend is exponential rather than linear. The exponential parameter is $\gamma$, and you can estimate it by OLS.

Comment: Ok, I see. But back to my question; if data generating process is linear, and I want to estimate $Y=\alpha+\beta \times t+\epsilon_t$, how is it possible? Is it legit? For instnce, in ADF test, it is commonly used $t$ as an independent variable, if time series has a trend; but I do not uderstand why it is legit, since $t$ is non-stationary.

Comment: @Duo, I have edited my answer to address you latest question. I do recommend looking at Hayashi's textbook. Only a few pages tell quite a bit of what you need to know.

Comment: Thanks, very much! I'll look through Hayashi's textbook as well.